# Spark MLlib - Training collaborative filtering with implicit feedback - strange warnings

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to build [Collaborative filtering](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) model on the user orders and getting some useful results with `ALS.train()` but I would like to try `ALS.trianImplicit()` but `trianImplicit()` is predicting just zeros on same dataset which `ASL.train()` I was getting decent predictions.

When using `ALS.trianImplicit()` to train the model I was getting following warnings:

```
15/09/01 15:39:29 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
15/09/01 15:39:29 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

Does this indicate that it was an **error** and not warnings and model just could not train anything because of missing libraries?

Comment: These are not strange warnings. You'll need to install the [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) library

Comment: That warning may just harm performance a bit but you can perform the model training without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @eliasah has pointed out this warnings an not-critical, but may slow down performance. Using native BLAS can result in a huge performance improvement. There are some instructions on https://github.com/amplab/ml-matrix/blob/master/EC2.md on how to setup Spark + BLAS on EC2.

If your cluster is running Ubuntu you can install the following packages:

```
libblas3gf
libblas-doc
libblas-dev

liblapack3gf
liblapack-doc
liblapack-dev
```

However, some people have reported better performance from using http://www.openblas.net/ so you can try installing that on your workers. You will also need to include `com.github.fommil.netlib` with your application (Spark currently uses version 1.1.2).

Comment: what are the equivalent packages for centos 6.5 ?